# neo4j incompatible types: String cannot be converted to file

Tags: netbeans, neo4j

I have looked at other solutions, but in my case is related with neo4j, when I added the line:

```
graphDb = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase(DB_PATH);
```

My DB_PATH is

```
DB_PATH = "C:/Users/herandr/Downloads/neo4j-community2";
```

I´m using netbeans, I couldn´t create a Maven project, due to proxy issues. So I added all the libraries from Neo4j lib/

I just installed Netbeans, so I wonder as well if there is a package missing.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at the signature of newEmbeddedDatabase ? It expects a **File**, not a **String**. Check http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/factory/GraphDatabaseFactory.html ...

Hope this helps,

Regards,
Tom

Comment: Thank you, before it used to accept string. I changed it to File in that case